# input of a tuple on the command line and assigning it to a tuple

Tags: python-2.7, input, tuples, prompt

I want to input pairs of coordinates (points) to define a line (vector) and want to do somthing like:

```
var = raw_input("Input LineA (x1,y1,x2,y2) ")

lineA[0][0]=var[0]
lineA[1][0]=var[1]
lineA[0][1]=var[2]
lineA[1][1]=var[3]
print lineA
```

lineA should be used as a tuple of tuples, á la:

```
lineA = ((2.5,2.0),(3.0,4.0))
```

Anyone any clue how to solve this elegantly? At present I'm getting

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "win.py", line 34, in
 <module>
    lineA[0][0]=var[0] TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lineA = ((var[0], var[2]), (var[1], var[3]))
```

Tuples are *immutable* so you can't assign values to its individual elements (as opposed to lists).

@Edit1:
Sorry I didn't pay attention to the 1st line. Here's an update:

```
raw_str = raw_input("Input LineA (x1,y1,x2,y2): ")
# Split the string by commas(this is the separator), raise Exception if we have more or less than 4 values.
tokens = raw_str.split(",")
if len(tokens) != 4:
    raise ValueError("Invalid input.")
# Now we eliminate any SPACEs, TABs, or ; that the user might have input and then convert everything to floats.
var = [item.strip(" \t;") for item in tokens]
lineA = ((float(var[0]), float(var[2])), (float(var[1]), float(var[3])))
```

Comment: I found that input() works smoother than raw_input(). Got it working now.

Comment: Ah yes, `input` also evaluates the user input.